# Shell: Is there a difference between / and // in directories?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm making this tiny program in Shell:

```
#***************************************************************
# Function.
# NAME: chk_df
# Synopsis:
# Check if a local directory (dirName) exist and has a file (fileName).
# 
# 
# The return codes are the following:
# 99 : dirName does not exists
#  0 : dirName exists and has fileName
#  1 : dirName exists and has not fileName
#
# Parameters:
# In values: dirName <string> fileName <string>
# Out values: returnCode <int>
# 
# How to use:
# chk_df dirName fileName
#***************************************************************
chk_df(){
   # Check the number of arguments that could be passed.
   # In this case, two, dirName, fileNAme.
   if [[ ${#@} != 2 ]]; then
       echo "Error ...Use [Function]: chk_df <dirName> <fileName>"
       echo "Ex: chk_df /foo lola.txt"
       exit
   fi   

   DIR=$1
   FILE=$2      

   [[ ! -d $DIR ]] && return 99
   [[ -d $DIR && ! -e $DIR/$FILE ]] && return 1
   [[ -d $DIR && -e $DIR/$FILE ]] && return 0

}
```

Because I need to check if a file is in a directory, I did this (horrible?) patch **$DIR/$FILE** , but things like this could happen:

```
I) If we do: chk_df /foo lola.txt
We get: /foo/lola.txt

II) If we do: chk_df /foo/ lola.txt
We get: /foo//lola.txt [Notice the //]
```

In both cases the code seems to work. **Why?** I read that backslash acts like a **space**. So, could I put **n** backslash without unknown problems?

Could I leave it like that or it will bring problems? Is there a difference? UNIX assume it to the right way?

**EXTRA QUESTION**: why I can not do the returns with negative numbers? This is:   **return -1**

Comment: Post the extra question seperately in `unix.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Thank you, I read the answer in a wiki: `Unix exit statuses are restricted to values 0-255, the range of an unsigned 8-bit integer`. Only asking if there was a way to bypass this. I will write it in another question.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and/12291#12291

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/` , `//`, or any string of consecutive slashes have the same meaning according to the POSIX standard, with the exception that they *may* have a different meaning at the beginning of a path (so `/foo` and `//foo` may denote different objects). Linux does not use this exception, so any number of consecutive slashes always means the same thing as a single `/`.

(The exception is there to cater to the needs of other Unix-like systems that use leading `//` to denote a network path.)

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend me that, with code, assure me the put only one `/` to sanitize the code. This is: if I have two or more consecutive `/`, replace it just with one `/`? In your opinion, is this necessary?

Comment: @Kani: it's slightly safer to use single slashes since you're less likely to hit `PATH_MAX`. It's also nicer if you output paths for user consumption or when you store them somewhere. It's usually not really necessary, so decide for yourself.

Comment: Answer from [Unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and/12291#12291)

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: yeah, or [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file/6178#6178), moved from SO.

Answer (score 1):

There are no difference.

// = /

Answer (score 0):

You can, in principle, use as many `/` separators as you want (until you start hitting `PATH_MAX` or some other hard limitation):

```
$ ls /usr/bin///////////////less
/usr/bin///////////////less
```

One problem you'll run into is if you ever want to test that two paths are the same[*], because /usr/bin/less and /usr/bin//less are the same path but are different strings. It can be useful to canonicalise paths before comparison.

[*] Ignoring the fact that different paths can refer to the same object.